# VBA excel: How to choose session in SAP

Tags: vba, excel-2010, sap-gui

I have the following question, I have two sessions/windows open in my SAP `F6P` system and I need to tell both to do different jobs. How can it send commands for both sessions ?

Please take a look into the following code, I found which number is the session but I don't know how to call it.

Please note that if I log in SAP and open two sessions then the first seems to be with number 1 and the second with number two. If now I delete the second one and create a new on, system understand the third as third and not as second.

[image]

The code is the following:

```
    Sub SAP_activesession()
    If Not IsObject(App) Then
       Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
       Set App = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
       Set Connection = App.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Session) Then
       Set Session = Connection.Children(1)
    End If
    If IsObject(wscript) Then
       wscript.ConnectObject Session, "on"
       wscript.ConnectObject App, "on"
    End If
    'Set Session = App.ActiveSession
    
    'Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    'Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nf-28"
    Dim sn, ss, su, st, session_number_all, syn, sid, client
          ' ðëçèïò áíïéêôþí session
    'sn = Session.info.SessionNumber                         ' íïõìåñï ôïõ session
    'ss = Session.info.systemname                            ' system name
    'su = Session.info.User                                  ' user name
    'st = Session.info.transaction                           ' transaction
    
    
    'MsgBox ("session count :" & sc & " " & sn & " " & su & " " & st)
    
    Dim NoSession: Dim time1, time2
    
    session_number_all = Connection.Children.Count: MsgBox (session_number_all)
    For NoSession = 0 To session_number_all - 1 Step 1
        Set Session = Connection.Children(Int(NoSession))       'epilegeis session
        
        sn = Session.info.SessionNumber                         ' íïõìåñï ôïõ session
        ss = Session.info.systemname                            ' system name
        su = Session.info.User                                  ' user name
        st = Session.info.transaction                           ' transaction
        sid = Session.info.systemsessionid                      ' session id
        syn = Session.info.systemnumber                         ' system number
        client = Session.info.client
    
        MsgBox ("Total session: " & session_number_all & vbNewLine & _
                    "Session number: " & sn & vbNewLine & _
                    "Session children: " & session_number_all & vbNewLine & _
                    "Session system: " & ss & vbNewLine & _
                    "Session user: " & su & vbNewLine & _
                    "Session transaction: " & st & vbNewLine & _
                    "Session Id: " & sid & vbNewLine & _
                    "System No: " & syn & vbNewLine & _
                    "Client: " & client)
                    
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = sn & "." & st
    
            time1 = Now
            time2 = Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")
                Do Until time1 >= time2
                    DoEvents
                    time1 = Now()
                Loop
    
            'Set Session = Connection.Children.ITEM(NoSession)
            
        On Error Resume Next
    Next NoSession
    
    End Sub
```

Thank you in advance,
Vassilis

Comment: https://blogs.sap.com/2012/11/19/how-to-select-a-specific-session-to-do-sap-gui-scripting-activities-inside-it/

Comment: It's not an issue to work with multiple screens, but could you clarify how you decide to work with one or another? Based on the currently opened transaction code (F-28/FBL5N)? Do you want to just select 2 open sessions randomly? To open 1 new session if only 1 is open?